# Dawn Theme Shopify Custom Section

Tags: json, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am working to add in Dawn Theme Shopify custom static section under Add to Cart Button on product page. I am adding in product.json file Getting Error

I look to add static product section in Dawn Theme.[image]

I am using Dawn Theme and How to add product image under Add to Cart.

Any help Appreciated.

Thanks

Code:

},
"buy_buttons": {
"type": "buy_buttons",
"settings": {
"show_dynamic_checkout": true,
"show_gift_card_recipient": true
}

```
{% section 'static-product' %}
```

Error message = "Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON.